# c++ Trouble casting overloaded function: <unresolved overloaded function type>

Tags: c++, casting, overloading

I have functions in a superclass designed to associate a string with internal functions:

```
class Base
{
    typedef std::function<void(double)> double_v;

    bool registerInput(std::string const& key, double_v const& input) {
        functions[key] = input;
    }

    void setInput(std::string key, double value) {
        auto fit = functions.find(key);
        if (fit == functions.end()) return;

        fit->second(value);
    }

    std::map<std::string, double_v> functions;
}
```

The idea being that any subclass I can register functions can call them with a string and value:

```
SubBase::SubBase() : Base(){
    Base::registerInput(
        "Height", 
        static_cast<void (*)(double)>(&SubBase::setHeight)
    );
}

void SubBase::setHeight(double h) {
....
}
```

Which could then be called with:

```
subBaseInstance.setInput("Height", 2.0);
```

However when I compile I'm getting the following error:

```
In constructor ‘SubBase::SubBase()’
error: invalid static_cast from type ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to type ‘void (*)(double)’
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Member functions aren't functions. That doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SubBase` is not `static`, so it has an implicit first argument of `SubBase*` (the object you call the member function for). Hence the signature is `void (*) (SubBase*, double)`. In C++11 you can probably (I'm not completely sure) cast it to a `function<void (SubBase*, double)>`.

Using lambda functions, you can do the following:

```
SubBase::SubBase() : Base(){
    auto myself = this;
    Base::registerInput( 
        "Height",  
        [myself] (double v) { myself->setHeight (v); }
    ); 
} 

void SubBase::setHeight(double h) { 
.... 
}
```

Comment: This indeed works perfectly - is it trivial to extend this to work for functions that accept other data types (int) (Base*)?

Comment: there are often more than one type a method can accept, basic types like double, int and unsigned, but subclasses of Base can feed back into themselves - something along the lines of:
[myself](int v){myself->setHeight(v);}
[myself](SubBase2 v){myself->setHeight(v);}
There are appropriate methods, but storing them in the same map seems to be working against the language.

Comment: Never mind - I was trying to be too clever - far easier to just keep maps of different input types.

Answer (score 4):

As others noted, the types doesn't match. However you could use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) for it to work:

```
Base::registerInput(
    "Height", 
    std::bind(&SubBase::setHeight, *this, std::placeholders::_1)
);
```

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that the function type should be `std::function<void(double)>`...

Comment: In my quest to make this more generic, I tried both this and ForEveR's answer, and both ended up with the same error message as my original problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef std::function<void(double)> double_v;
```

It's `function-pointer`.

```
static_cast<void (*)(double)>(&SubBase::setHeight)
```

It's `member-function pointer`. They are not convertible to each other.

You can use `std::bind` for this

```
SubBase::SubBase() : Base(){
    Base::registerInput(
        "Height", 
        std::bind(&SubBase::setHeight, this, std::placeholders::_1)
    );
```