# assigning std::function to a member function

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

```
class A {
public:
  std::function<void(int)> f_;
  void print_num(int i) {
    cout << i;
  }
  void setFuntion(std::function<void(int)> f) {
    f_=f;
  }
  void run() {
    setFunction(print_num);
  }
};
```

this doesn't work. i get `note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘std::function<void(int)>’` and other errors.

If I put the definition of `print_num` outside of the class. everything works. i tried adding `&A::`, `A::` and `this.` nothing helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print_num` is a non-static member function, which means that it has an implicit first argument of type `A*`. You can, for instance, pass that by using a lambda:

```
void run() { 
    auto myself = this;
    setFunction( [myself] (int i) { myself->print_num (i); } ); 
}
```

or use `bind`, see here

[c++ Trouble casting overloaded function: <unresolved overloaded function type>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294616/c-trouble-casting-overloaded-function-unresolved-overloaded-function-type/12294672#12294672)

Comment: ehh, and i thought std::function should have made things easier :-(

Comment: `setFunction( [this] (int i) { this->print_num (i); } );` also worked

Comment: Using `[this]` makes a copy of the object, so you probably want `[&this]`, or just `[&]`.

Comment: Does it? `this` is a pointer, so using `[this]` should make a copy of the pointer.